# How to get latex math into org headline

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Putting a math element into an org mode headline causes latex to complain. ie

```
* This contains $\prod_{k=1}^N$ math
Lorem ipsum
```

gives

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 29.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\prod@' on input line 29.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\slimits@' on input line 29.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `subscript' on input line 29.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `superscript' on input line 29.
```

Comment: Ok I seem to have found the answer hidden in the org mode mailing list:
https://list.orgmode.org/olu4mtn48ve.fsf@med.uni-goettingen.de/T/#m069b22b7e10ad6d967fc535c722f4dc52ba41b40
Will see if I can clean it up with a macro and post answer

Comment: @NickD Its rendered but it has hyperref/inputenc related errors

Comment: Ok just now Im only getting the warnings not the full errors. Will need to see what (other environments?) were upgrading to errors

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10555/hyperref-warning-token-not-allowed-in-a-pdf-string

Answer (score 2):

After posting I found a reference in the Org mode [mailing list](https://list.orgmode.org/olu4mtn48ve.fsf@med.uni-goettingen.de/T/#m069b22b7e10ad6d967fc535c722f4dc52ba41b40) showing how to get round this issue.

Following: the first headline shows org developer Nicolas Goaziou's solution. The second shows how to tighten it a bit with an org mode macro `mt` which takes math ($$ implied) in arg-1 and equivalent ASCII in arg-2 to keep hyperref happy.

```
#+MACRO: mt @@latex:\texorpdfstring{$ $1 $}{$2}@@
# mt = math-text
* This contains @@latex:\texorpdfstring{$\prod_{k=1}^N$}{product 1toN}@@ math
Lorem ipsum
* This is better {{{mt(\prod_{k=3}^N,product 1toN)}}} math
Dolor sit amet.
```